# Android Studio 1.1.0 Render Error

Tags: android-studio

I cannot seem to get the UI to render in Android Studio.
I've never encountered this issue before.

I've tried switching API targets & I've reinstalled Android Studio.

```
Render error
ActiveTool: com.intellij.designer.designSurface.tools.SelectionTool@49803f68
SDK: Android 5.0.1 - API 21
java.lang.RuntimeException: Class file too large!
    at org.jetbrains.asm4.ClassWriter.toByteArray(ClassWriter.java:777)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ClassConverter.rewriteClass(ClassConverter.java:70)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ClassConverter.rewriteClass(ClassConverter.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.convertClass(RenderClassLoader.java:160)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClass(RenderClassLoader.java:144)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFile(RenderClassLoader.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFile(ProjectClassLoader.java:284)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromClassPath(RenderClassLoader.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFromModule(ProjectClassLoader.java:199)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFromModuleOrDependency(ProjectClassLoader.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:53)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses(Class.java:1735)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.parseClass(ViewLoader.java:494)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClass(ViewLoader.java:478)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClassSilently(ViewLoader.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadAndParseRClass(LayoutlibCallback.java:635)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.<init>(RenderService.java:356)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.create(RenderService.java:231)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:475)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem with Android Studio 2.0 and solved the problem by creating any new project in Android Studio. It's probably a bug of Android Studio that has not been fixed in version 2.0.